# Is it worth it performance-wise to do OpenGL+OpenCV entirely thru the NDK NativeActivity instead of thru the Java SDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm about to start working on an augmented reality project that will involve using the EPSON Moverio AR glasses or similar. Assuming we go for those glasses, they run on Android 4.0.4 - API 15. The app will involve near realtime analysis of video (frames from the glasses camera) for feature detection / tracking with markers and overlaying 3d objects in the 'real world' based on the markers.

So far then, on the technical side, it looks like we'll be dealing with:

1. API 15
2. OpenCV
3. OpenGLES2

Considering the above, I'm wondering if it's worth doing it all thru the NDK, using a single `NativeActivity` with the `android_native_app_glue` code. When I say worth it I mean performance wise.

Sure, doing it all on the C/C++ side has for instance the advantage that the code could then potentially be ported with minimal modification to run on other environments. But OpenCV does have Java bindings for Android and GL can also be used to a certain extent from Java. So I'm just wondering if performance-wise it's worth it or it would be about the same as, say, using a `GLSurfaceView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work in augmented reality. The vast majority of applications I've seen have been native. Google recommends avoiding native application unless the gains are absolutely necessary. I think AR is one of the relatively few cases where it is necessary. The benefits I'm aware of are:

1. Native camera access will allow you to get a higher capture framerate. Passing the data to the Java layer considerably slows this down. Even OpenCV's non-native capture can be slower in Java because OpenCV primary maintains the data in native objects. Your capture framerate is a limiting factor on how fast you can update the pose information for your objects. Beware though, OpenCV's native camera [will not work on devices running Qualcomm's MSM optimized fork of android](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3995) - this includes many snapdragon devices.
2. Every call to an OpenGL method in Java not only has a cost related to dropping into native, and they also perform quite a few additional checks. Look through [GLES20.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/core/jni/android_opengl_GLES20.cpp) which contains the native implementation of the GLES20 class's methods. You'll see that you could bypass quite a lot of logic by using native calls. This is fine in most mobile application, but 3D rendering often gets a significant benefit from bypassing those checks and the JNI overhead. This is even more important in AR because your will already be swamping the system with CV processing.
3. You will very likely want your detection related code in native. OpenCV have samples if you want to see the difference between native and Java detection performance. The former will use fewer resources and be more consistent. Using a native application means that you can call your native functions without paying the cost of passing large amount of data from Java to native.
4. Native sensor access is more efficient and the rate says far more consistent in native thanks to the lack of garbage collection and JNI. This is relevant if you will be using IMU data interesting ways.

You may be able to build an non-native application that has most of it's code in native and runs well despite being Java based, but it is considerably more difficult.

Comment: I was just looking at the METAIO sdk as a viable alternative to OpenCV, and just realized the lib they provide for Android is for Java (at least as the official way of using it). And the performance is totally fine. So I'm wondering again if I even need to go native really.

Comment: It seems like you'd strongly prefer to avoid native. If you find that METAIO plus rendering with the Java OpenGL wrapper performs well enough for your use case, then go ahead. I'm used to seeing AR projects feel slightly less responsive once everything is running, especially on the weaker target devices. I may be biased by working on particular intensive apps (VIN, SLAM, ect). 

If it wouldn't be too time intensive, I'd recommend making two minimal prototypes, native and non-native, that do the most expensive operations of your app and compare them so you can make your choice with confidence.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm not particularly biased to non-native. Actually, I like C/C++ better. I was just asking so as to not make things harder on myself if I didn't need to. I'm actually still considering going native.

Comment: I also have another question, more specific to computer vision. Would you mind taking a look and maybe sharing your thoughts on this one? I can post it as a new question on SO, or link you to it: https://helpdesk.metaio.com/questions/46000/how-to-measure-accuracy-of-marker-tracking or we could also discuss in a chat if you have time. Thanks again!